# Cannot start pyspark. Unable to locate a Java Runtime

Tags: pyspark

I am attempting to use pyspark on a Mac. I have installed pyspark (`pip install pyspark`) and also openJDK (`brew install openjdk@11`) however when I try and run pyspark:

`> pyspark`

it fails with

> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Any advice on how to fix would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. I needed to export JAVA_HOME

`export JAVA_HOME=/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`